# how to add ` character to sql queries in cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a table with special fields name such as 'from' and 'order'

(this table used with another cms and I can't change table structor)

I want add a record using cakephp 3 ,but I got 'Database Error'.

it seems queries of cakephp 3 is not sanintized with ` character!

my code in controler:

```
$tour = $this->Tours->patchEntity($tour, $this->request->data);
$this->Tours->save($tour);
```

generated SQL is:

```
INSERT INTO tour_tours 
       (title, from , to, description, duration) 
VALUES 
       ('tour title', 'from', 'to', 'description of tour', 7)
```

SQL Query has syntax error...

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add 

`'quoteIdentifiers' => true`

in your datasource configuration as stated in the doc

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#configuration

Answer (score 1):

Either you can configure your **Datasources** from 'quoteIdentifiers' => false to 'quoteIdentifiers' => true at app.php

OR

One of your columns is using a column name that is reserved by [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/keywords.html).

As you can see that **FROM** and **ORDER** is a reserve word by MYSQL, you can try changing these words from your database tables. Hoping it works.

> For example: "tour_tours" table has a "from" field which makes you the Database Error. so please change these fields from your table and re-try.